# How to use adb to take dumpstate logs on a Samsung device during device setup after first power on?

Tags: adb, samsung, usb-debugging, logging, debug

I need to get dumpstate logs on a Samsung Fold device during device setup after first power on (after new binary flashing or factory reset).

I am unable to set debug level high through *#9900# because the device is switching on for the first time.

Is there a way to do this through adb? I have a custom ROM in which adb is pre-enabled.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Unless you have flashed a custom ROM with pre-enabled adb mode, adb will not be available until you have finished device-setup, activated debugging menu and there enabled adb.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for your response. Yes, I have a custom ROM in which adb is pre-enabled.

Comment: I am not quite sure if that is helpful but you can install sidebar lite from adb and do anything you want on initial setup screen, like open dialer and type the code (sure there is a more straightforward way)